# EF Code First accessing HasMaxLength value

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to get the max length of a column I have defined using EF code first.  I need to ensure that the value inserted does not exceed the max length:

```
this.Property(t => t.COMPANY_ID)
             .HasMaxLength(30);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are on .NET Framework 4.3 or newer built-in validation should verify this for you and throw an exception in case of violation. Does not this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood your question, your real need seems to be that you want to make sure that a property of an entity (in this case the COMPANY_ID) does not exceed a certain maximum length (in this case 30).

Instead of performing manual checks like that, you can consider making use of Data Annotations (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema), especially since you're using code first anyway. Something like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MyProperty {get; set;}
    [Column(TypeName="Date")]
    public DateTime MyDate {get; set;}
}
```

You can set more than just the maximum length. As you can see above you can specify what data type should reflect in your database. You can also specify if a property is required and many more. EF will manage this for you automatically and will raise exceptions for you if your entities do not meet the criteria set by your data annotations. If you use MVC scaffolding, it can automatically generate validations as well that are consistent with the annotations you've specified for your entities.